# R ggplot2: filling the space between 2 lines with varying x values (geom_ribbon) and formatting log axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, ribbon, logarithm, axis-labels

I am trying to fill the space between two curves, however geom_ribbon uses varying y values rather than x values. My y axis is depth so I don't really want to swap the axes over. Is there any way to do this? Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
Statsrep <- structure(list(Depth = c(34L, 74L, 114L, 164L, 204L, 264L, 304L, 344L, 384L, 424L, 
464L, 504L, 554L), Min = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Max = c(38, 105, 86, 44, 68, 
155, 160, 68, 120, 1670, 178, 110, 84), Average = c(5.64, 12.08, 17.42, 6.5, 11.59, 11.09, 10.1, 
9.09, 8.08, 38.96, 15.94, 6.53, 13.21), Mode = c(2,2,3,2,6,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)), .Names = 
c("Depth", "Min", "Max", "Average", "Mode"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L), class = "data.frame")
Statsrep
```

The code i am currently using is:

```
Statsrep <- read.csv(file="filename.csv", header=TRUE, sep=" ")
p1 <- ggplot(data = Statsrep, aes(xmin=Min, xmax=Max, y=Depth)) +
geom_ribbon(aes(fill="#CCCCCC"))
p1 <- p1 + coord_trans(x = "log10") + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 1500)) +
ylim(600,0)
p1 <- p1 + layer(geom = "path")
p1 + xlab("GRAINSIZE / mm")
p1 + ylab("DEPTH / m")
```

Also, I want to customise my log x axis so that there are 1, 10, 100, 1000 labels showing and equally spaced, similar to log graph paper. This code only shows 100, 1000, 1500 that are bunched up toward the right of the axis. Is there any way to format the axis like this?
Thanks for any help in advance. Holly

Comment: Could you please make it reproducible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: My apologies. I hope that makes it a little easier? I wasn't sure how to call the data from the list so you may have to save it to a csv file - sorry....

Comment: That has definitely solved the issue thank you both so much!!! You have just put an end to countless hours of frustration. Holly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess she wants the depth to go downwards

```
  ggplot(data = Statsrep, aes(ymin=Min, ymax=Max, x=Depth, y = Average)) +
  geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +
  scale_y_log10("GRAINSIZE / mm", breaks=c(1, 10, 100, 1000)) +
  scale_x_reverse("DEPTH / m", limits = c(600,0)) + 
  coord_flip()
```

The graph looks diferent because I'm using a custom theme for the whole session.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This may help you get started, though I'm still not entirely sure what you're after:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = Statsrep, aes(ymin=Min, ymax=Max, x=Depth,y = Average)) +
        geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.5) + 
        geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +
        scale_y_log10() + 
        coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that is the sort of thing I was after, thank you so much for your help! Holly